# How Do I Use a CSV File To Send Keys?

Tags: python, csv, email, selenium

I am a beginner and I've tried searching online everywhere, but I'm not sure I'm searching the right terms.

My CSV file looks this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B74bmJNIxxW-dWl0Y0dsV1E4bjA/view?usp=sharing

I want to know how to use the CSV file to do something like this,

## Email

driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress').send_keys("johndoe@example.com")

print "Successfully Entered Email..."

Comment: Google "python csv" and learn how to read values from a CSV. Once you have understood how to do that you can start thinking about selenium.

Comment: Post the csv file text itself here so we can easily copy it.

Comment: Also, consider an example with different email names!

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks. I uploaded the CSV!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways that you could do this. One would be to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```
with open("foo.csv", "r") as fh:
    lines = csv.reader(fh)
    for line in lines:
        address = line[0]
        driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress').send_keys(address)
```

Answer (score 1):

It really helps to post the data here so that we see what the format really is and run code ourselves. So, I invented some sample data

*emails.csv*

```
Email,Password,First Name,Last Name,City
foo1@example.com,frobinate,John,Doe,District Heights
foo2@example.com,frobinate,John,Doe,District Heights
foo3@example.com,frobinate,John,Doe,District Heights
foo4@example.com,frobinate,John,Doe,District Heights
```

I can use the `csv` module to read that. `csv.DictReader` reads each row into its own `dict` that lets me reference cells by the name given in the header. Since I'll be looking up records by email name later, I'll read it into another `dict` that will act as an index into the records. If the same user is in there multiple times, only the last one will be remembered.

With the index in place, I can grab the row by email name.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('emails.csv', newline='') as fp:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(fp) # auto-reads header
...     for row in reader:
...         email_index[row['Email']] = row
... 
>>> for item in email_index.items():
...     print(item)
... 
('foo3@example.com', {'Email': 'foo3@example.com', 'City': 'District Heights', 'First Name': 'John', 'Password': 'frobinate', 'Last Name': 'Doe'})
('foo2@example.com', {'Email': 'foo2@example.com', 'City': 'District Heights', 'First Name': 'John', 'Password': 'frobinate', 'Last Name': 'Doe'})
('foo4@example.com', {'Email': 'foo4@example.com', 'City': 'District Heights', 'First Name': 'John', 'Password': 'frobinate', 'Last Name': 'Doe'})
('foo1@example.com', {'Email': 'foo1@example.com', 'City': 'District Heights', 'First Name': 'John', 'Password': 'frobinate', 'Last Name': 'Doe'})
>>> 
>>> user = 'foo1@example.com'
>>> record = email_index[user]
>>> print("{Email} is {First Name} {Last Name} and lives in {City}".format(**record)) 
foo4@example.com is John Doe and lives in District Heights
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!